# Induction motor slip speed stator and slip difference

Tags: induction-motor

This is an induction motor question. What is the difference between **'synchronous speed of the stator field'** and **'the slip speed of the rotor'**? If you know the equation that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The **synchronous speed** n<sub>s</sub> of the stator field is directly related to the mains **frequency** and the number of (magnetic) **poles** in the stator and is expressed in revolutions per minute [rpm]:

$$n_s = \dfrac{120×f}{p} \text{[rpm]}$$

The **rotor speed** n<sub>r</sub> is is the number of revolutions per minute of the rotor.

**Slip** is the **ratio** of the speed [*difference* between stator and rotor] to stator field speed. Slip is defined as:

$$s=\dfrac{n_s-n_r}{n_s} $$

So if the rotor is:

- at the same speed as the magnetic field then **slip is 0**;
- at a lower speed than the magnetic field then **slip is positive** (for normal motor mode this is in the order of 5%);
- at a higher speed than the magnetic field then the **slip is negative**. The motor is in generator mode.

[Li-aung Yip explained in his comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87806/induced-motor-slip-speed-stator-and-slip-difference/87820?noredirect=1#comment172771_87820) that **slip speed** is probably defined by the difference in stator speed and rotor speed, in other words: "the slip percentage expressed in RPM":

$$s_{rpm}=n_s-n_r$$

Comment: I'm guessing the "slip speed" is just the slip percentage expressed in RPM.

Comment: @Li-aungYip ah that makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The Sync speed is the speed of the rotating magnetic field in the stator.

Ns = (freq * 120)/P

Freq=60hz
P=number of poles
Ns= Sync speed RPM

Slip Speed (RPM)

Nslip = Ns - Nmotor

Nmotor = Speed of motor RPM.