# Calculating speed of the rotor with slip

Tags: motor, induction-motor, single-phase, rotor

The question i'm having trouble with is:

**Calculate the speed of the rotor of a  6 pole induction motor with a slip of 2.2%. The motor is connected to a 230V single-phase supply.**

I am familiar with the table below and a certain formulae but i'm doing something incorrect and am confused on how to tackle this question.

Any formulaes or help would be appriciated as I am really stuck

[image]

Comment: *"i'm doing something incorrect "* Start with showing us what you do, even if you know it is incorrect. Homework question with no attempt at a solution will be closed. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036)

Comment: Which "certain formulae" have you tried? Do you know the supply frequency?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework or study problem with no demonstration of attempt to solve?

Comment: If the voltage is 230V what is the likely supply frequency? Having got that go to your course  documentation and look up the formula for slip.;

Comment: the calculation im doing is 120-50hz/6 = 1000

Comment: Which is the wrong answer the correct answer is 963 but im bot sure what im doing wrong

Comment: 963 is not the correct answer. You have either copied that to your comment incorrectly or your source is incorrect. You have only the very first of many formulae of induction motors. If you want to learn about induction motors, you need to find a textbook or tutorial site that presents all of of the material in an orderly manner with diagrams etc. We can not write out a textbook page here for every question. However, you can find a lot of material in the answers to previous questions here. Look at the related questions listed on this page.

Comment: Look at: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87806/induced-motor-slip-speed-stator-and-slip-difference

Comment: The question cannot be answered using an absolute value without knowing the supply frequency anyway. You will have different answers at 50Hz or 60Hz (neither of which is 963...)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward. The slip= (ws-wr)/ws,
where ws= 1000 rpm at 50 Hz and 1200 at 60 Hz ,
wr is the speed of the motor ,

wr at 50 Hz = 1000(1-2.2%) = 978 rpm,
wr at 60 Hz = 1200(1-2.2%) = 1173.6 rpm